# Como puedo cambiar el orden de las lineas en java?

Tags: java

tengo una duda,como puedo cambiar el orden de las lineas en java? Por ejemplo, en un .txt la linea 1 ponerlade ultima, la 2 de penúltima, etc.

Por ejemplo de:

```
134424
223123
323413
412312
```

A esto:

```
412312
323413
223123
13442e
```

Comment: Par ayudarte necesitamos que pongas el código que has intentado para solucionar tu problema.
Como consejo para tu solución creo que puedes emplear una Pila, ya que en esta estructura de datos el primer elemento en entrar es el último en salir, con lo cual tendrías las líneas invertidas tal y como quieres.

Comment: No tengo ningún código dado que no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola te dejo una simple solucion, evidentemente se puede mejorar un monto pero se entiende el proceso de lectura y escritura de la informacion en orden inverso.

```
public class ReverseLines {

    public static List<String> readLines(final File file) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lines.add(line);
        }

        scanner.close();
        return lines;
    }

    public static void writeLines(final File file, List<String> data) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);

        for (int i = data.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            printWriter.println(data.get(i));
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Starting process");

        File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\USAA\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        List<String> lines = readLines(myFile);

        writeLines(myFile, lines);

        System.out.println("Process finished");

    }
}
```